# Undefined method `permit' for "update":String - in controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I got the error when I'm trying to update through a form. It says:

> undefined method `permit' for "update":String

```
def update
  if @action.update(action_params)
   redirect_to action_path(@action)
  else
   flash[:errors] = @action.errors.full_messages
   flash[:data] = action_params
   redirect_to edit_action_path
  end
end

def set_action
  @action = Action.find(params[:id])
end

def action_params
  params.require(:action).permit(:name, :goal_id, :completed, :date)
end
```

Comment: are you starting with Rails ? if so, you just found a reserved variable. Name your controller and maybe models in a different way, at least the one in your controller. `@action` and `action` are reserved in a controller scope.

Comment: Another thing that would help you debug this (continuing what others have said) is to print out `params`. If you do that, you’ll see that you have `{:controller => 'your_controller', :action => 'update'}`.

Comment: Yes only started coding a few weeks ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails `params` there is automatically an `:action` key which is tied to any page load. You need to change your form model to a different name.